# Sending raw data through USB to any device on the other side

Tags: android, usb, device

I wish to write an Android app that sends data over USB without it having to detect a specific device or accessory on the other side - in other words, whether it detects anything or not on the other end, just send raw data over a particular port or interface.

I'm relatively new to this type of low-level development through Android, so if I'm using the incorrect terminology or misunderstanding how USB works properly, please forgive me.

The device that the app will send data to will be a "dumb" device.  It will not be sending any data back over the USB.  The device will essentially just receive raw data (basic bytes of information - integers, for example) and just do whatever it does once it receives the data.

Does USB require a handshake like TCP or is there a way to run it without headers or any of that garbage - just raw data?  And can Android operate in such a mode (unrooted)?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: As Preston says below, you can't really do that, at least not with the normal USB stack.  Possibly you can convince the hardware to do it if you entirely re-write the operating-system level drivers to not care about lack of response, but even then, there may be parts of the protocol built as assumptions into the design of hardware state machines.  USB just isn't for dumb devices - but they don't have to be very "smart" beyond what is required to implement USB itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this with USB unless it is using something like a USB to UART bridge.

This sounds like you want something more like serial communication, the TX/RX lines just go low or high and something on the other side interprets this data and consumes it.

USB is a protocol, so you can't just dump data on the bus and expect something useful to happen. Using a USB to Serial bridge allows you to use USB like you require, but there is a serial layer on top where you can dump the raw data.